# Tomcat 7 to 8.5 - running an external web app

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a web application developed with eclipse/gradle with many components. The classes are under the /bin in each eclipse subproject, and the dependency jars are copied to ~/local_tomcat_dependencies (as a convenience by my gradle build). In my examples here, I've cut out most of the projects and jars. I configured Tomcat 7 to run it with the following ROOT.xml, and it works perfectly (and for dev purposes has been for years, while in production it runs on Tomcat 8.5):

```
<Context path="/" docBase="/Users/jeffp/myproject/system/web/src/main/webapp/">
<Loader className="org.apache.catalina.loader.VirtualWebappLoader"
    virtualClasspath="/Users/jeffp/myproject/system/database/bin;/Users/jeffp/myproject/system/util/bin;/Users/jeffp/myproject/system/main/bin;/Users/jeffp/local_tomcat_dependencies/*.jar"/>
<JarScanner scanAllDirectories="true"/>
```

The method of doing this changed in Tomcat 8, and I can no longer use Tomcat 7 because Spring 5 is incompatible with Tomcat 7. So, I am trying to use the new configuration of PostResources to load the app. I have struggled with it for hours but still can't quite get the app running. I can see something going on when Tomcat 8.5 starts, but it never fully loads. I think that the thing I am missing is having it find the WEB-INF/web.xml and start up the web app. I think that should have been taken care of with the first PostResources in my example below.

```
<Context>
<Resources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot" cachingAllowed="true" cacheMaxSize="1000000">
    <!-- dependency jars... -->
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" base="/Users/jeffp/myproject/system/web/src/main/webapp/" webAppMount="/" />
    <!-- eclipse bin dirs -->
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" base="/Users/jeffp/myproject/system/database/bin" internalPath="/" webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" base="/Users/jeffp/myproject/system/util/bin" internalPath="/" webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.DirResourceSet" base="/Users/jeffp/myproject/system/main/bin" internalPath="/" webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <!-- dependency jars (examples... there are a lot) -->
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet" base="/Users/jeffp/ww_local_tomcat_dependencies/antlr-2.7.7.jar" internalPath="/" webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet" base="/Users/jeffp/ww_local_tomcat_dependencies/asm-5.0.4.jar" internalPath="/" webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet" base="/Users/jeffp/ww_local_tomcat_dependencies/spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar" internalPath="/" webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet" base="/Users/jeffp/ww_local_tomcat_dependencies/spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar" internalPath="/" webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet" base="/Users/jeffp/ww_local_tomcat_dependencies/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar" internalPath="/" webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
    <PostResources className="org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet" base="/Users/jeffp/ww_local_tomcat_dependencies/spring-boot-starter-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar" internalPath="/" webAppMount="/WEB-INF/classes" />
</Resources>
```

There are no error messages in the log. The last line is:

```
07-Mar-2018 19:24:47.933 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying configuration descriptor [/Users/mbp/apache-tomcat-8.5.15/conf/Catalina/myproject/ROOT.xml]
```

I know that the jars are being scanned because of the cache size errors (not showing now because I added cacheMaxSize parameter).

What do I not have configured correctly?

Comment: Log messages? Errors? Catalina.out?

Comment: No errors. Again, I believe that the web.xml is not found by the first PostResources ... it's probably seeing all the jars and bin directories but not the actual web app.

Comment: if you don't put the main configuration files no one will help you.

Comment: Check out a thread dump. If Tomcat has stalled loading your web application, perhaps it's actually doing something. Maybe it's initializing some crypto service and you've run out of entropy.

Comment: @DBQ the configuration files have not changed.

Comment: @Christopher Schultz The tomcat process is idle, and this system has ample entropy.

Comment: So, how about that thread dump? Tomcat should produce a log entry that says "completed loading context XXX" or something similar. If it never gets there, there ought to be an error logged somewhere, or a thread stuck doing something. It's probably not entropy, but an idle system can still be starved for entropy.